# Подскажите пожалуйста как поставить чтобы страничка скачивалась?

Tags: php, javascript, css, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.button
    display: inline-block
    border: none
    color: #fff
    text-decoration: none
    background-color: #00529e
    padding: 15px 150px
    margin: 50px auto
    font-size: 13px
    text-transform: uppercase
    font-weight: 600
    letter-spacing: 3px
    border-radius: 2px
    text-align: center
    position: relative
    border-radius: 33px
    outline: none
    margin-left: 18%
    font-weight: bold
    transition: background-color .1s ease
    font-size: 20px
    &::after
        transition: background-color .2s ease
        position: absolute
        content: ''
        background-color: darken(#00529e, 50%)
        opacity: .18
        border-bottom-left-radius: 2px
        border-bottom-right-radius: 2px
        left: 0
    &:focus, &:hover
        text-decoration: none
        color: #fff
    &:hover
        background-color: lighten(#00529e, 5%)
        &::after
            opacity: .22
    &:active
        background-color: darken(#00529e, 5%)
        &::after
            opacity: .32
```

```html
<a class="button" download>скачать памятку</a>
```

m/YuSOi.png

Подскажите пожалуйста я прописал атрибут download этого достаточно чтобы страничка началась скачиваться ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тег  является одним из важных элементов HTML и предназначен для создания ссылок. В зависимости от присутствия атрибутов name или href тег  устанавливает ссылку или якорь. Якорем называется закладка внутри страницы, которую можно указать в качестве цели ссылки. При использовании ссылки, которая указывает на якорь, происходит переход к закладке внутри веб-страницы.
При наличии атрибута download браузер не переходит по ссылке, а предложит скачать документ, указанный в адресе ссылки.
(подробно: http://htmlbook.ru/html/a)

Comment: Дмитрий извините я тупой ничего не понял. И слепой сейчас посмотрю вашу ссылку

Comment: Если ВАС не затруднит можете показать код как должно выглядеть ?

Comment: как минимум вы не указали, то что вам необходимо скачать <a href="то что нужно скачать">

Comment: так прокатит <a href="index.html">  указать файл в котом я прописал ссылку прокатит ?

Comment: ну вообще то, судя по названию кнопки у вас должен быть какой нибудь файл типа doc, pdf и так далее

Comment: как заказчик прописал, тот я  и  сделал

Comment: ну не совсем понятно, зачем скачивать html

Comment: я вообще не знаю что он вообще собирается скачивать :)) Мне главное чтобы можно было скачать

Comment: Вариант сработает: <a href="images/xxx.jpg" download>Скачать файл</a>

Comment: Итог: <a href="index.html"  download>и все мне больше ничего не надо ?

Comment: понятно, спасибо